# Measuring force of tip using Jacobian function in KDL

Tags: ros, force, kdl, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I understand from [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_mechanism/Tutorials/Coding%20a%20realtime%20Cartesian%20controller%20with%20KDL) that you can use the Jacobian function from the KDL library to calculate a the torque to input for a desired force at the tip.
i.e. Torque = Jac(j,i)*Force

However, does anyone know a way to do the opposite, to measure the actual force exerted at the end tip by reading the respective measured joint torques.
i.e. Measured Force = [some function?]*measured torque at joints.

I tried using the [pr2_mechanism_model::JointState](http://ros.org/doc/groovy/api/pr2_mechanism_model/html/classpr2__mechanism__model_1_1JointState.html) to get the measured effort of each joint and use back the Jacobian Transform to get the measured force,

```
     for (unsigned int i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++)
  {
    F_measured_(i) = 0;
    for (unsigned int j = 0 ; j < kdl_chain_.getNrOfJoints() ; j++)
      F_measured_ += J_(i,j) * tau_measured_(j);
  }
```

However, when I can't compile it as the type for the JointState's measured force(double) is different from KDL::Wrench.

```
In member function ‘virtual void my_controller_ns::MyCartControllerClass::update()’:
  /home/c/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/my_controller_pkg/src/my_cart_controller_file.cpp:112:47: error: no match for ‘operator+=’ in ‘((my_controller_ns::MyCartControllerClass*)this)->my_controller_ns::MyCartControllerClass::F_measured_ += (((my_controller_ns::MyCartControllerClass*)this)->my_controller_ns::MyCartControllerClass::J_.KDL::Jacobian::operator()(i, j) * ((my_controller_ns::MyCartControllerClass*)this)->my_controller_ns::MyCartControllerClass::tau_measured_.KDL::JntArray::operator()(j, 0u))’
  /home/c/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/my_controller_pkg/src/my_cart_controller_file.cpp:112:47: note: candidate is:
  /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/orocos_kinematics_dynamics/orocos_kdl/install_dir/include/kdl/frames.inl:209:9: note: KDL::Wrench& KDL::Wrench::operator+=(const KDL::Wrench&)
  /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/orocos_kinematics_dynamics/orocos_kdl/install_dir/include/kdl/frames.inl:209:9: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘double’ to ‘const KDL::Wrench&’
```

Can anyone advise me on how do I go about measuring the force of the tip of pr2's arm using the Jacobian function in KDL? Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Thanks Peter, I appreciate any help as I am not very familiar with coding or robotics. Anyway, I realised I made a very silly mistake. The code should be

```
  for (unsigned int i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++)
  {
    F_measured_(i) = 0;
    for (unsigned int j = 0 ; j < kdl_chain_.getNrOfJoints() ; j++)
      F_measured_(i) += J_(i,j) * tau_measured_(j);
  }
```

I forgot the I wrote "F_measured_" instead of "F_measured_(i)" earlier. It can compile now but not sure if it actually works. Will let you know my results afterwards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59187/measuring-force-of-tip-using-jacobian-function-in-kdl/) by [ccm](https://answers.ros.org/users/604/ccm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 226 on 2013-03-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prashanthi tata](https://answers.ros.org/users/38936/prashanthi-tata/) on 2019-07-30**:
Hello!! Could you please help me in calculating force of tip when you know joint torques?? Seems like you are trying to implement the same, What type is F_measured_(i) ,J_(i,j) ,tau_measured_(j) ?? I defined tau_measured_(j) as KDL::JntArray , J_(i,j) ad KDL::jacobian. What should I define F_measured_(i) as??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure if it would helpfull somehow because I'm not very common with KDL. And may be I'm telling obvious things, but here is basic approach. Angular momentum conservation law: dH/dt = Sum(M) or in a simple case: J*dw/dt = Sum(Md) + Mc, where Md - disturbing torque (force) and Mc - control.

---

Originally posted by [Peter Listov](https://answers.ros.org/users/3071/peter-listov/) with karma: 338 on 2013-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0